# Can we have both ClickableTextCell and ButtonCell on the same column in GWT?

Tags: gwt, gwtp

Ok, I have an `IndexedColumn`

```
public class IndexedColumn extends Column<List<String>, String>{
    public IndexedColumn(int index){
       super(new ClickableTextCell()); // by default it is ClickableTextCell
    }
}
```

When creating column

```
IndexedColumn objectColumn=new IndexedColumn(6){
    @Override
    public String getCellStyleNames(Context context, List<String> object) {
        if (object.get(12).equals("button")){
            return getView().getRes().css().gwtCellButton();
        }
        else if(object.get(12).equals("1")){
            return getView().getRes().css().redColor();
        }
        return getView().getRes().css().myClickableTextCellStyle();
    }
}
```

//css

```
.myClickableTextCellStyleBold{
    font-weight:bold;
}
.myClickableTextCellStyleNormal{
    font-weight:normal !important;
}

.myClickableTextCellStyle, .myClickableTextCellStyleBold, .myClickableTextCellStyleNormal
{
    cursor: pointer;
    cursor: hand;
}
.gwt-Button, .gwtCellButton button, .gwtCellButtonSmall button {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 5px 7px;
  text-decoration: none;
  cursor: pointer;
  cursor: hand;
  font-size:small;
  background: black;
  border:1px solid #bbb;
  border-bottom: 1px solid #a0a0a0;
  border-radius: 3px;
 -moz-border-radius: 3px;
  color: white;

}
```

after ran, it can pick up the `getView().getRes().css().redColor()` but didn't pick up the `getView().getRes().css().gwtCellButton()`.

Is it possible to have both ClickableTextCell and ButtonCell on the same column, if it is, then how to do it?

Answer (score 0):

You will have to implement `HasCell` interface for the two classes, i.e. TextCell and ButtonCell, and then use the `CompositeCell` to club two(or more) cells together.

Use the following classes:

```
public abstract class CustomTextCell<T> extends AbstractCell<String> {

private T object;
private Set<String> set ;

@Override
public Set<String> getConsumedEvents() {
    set = new HashSet<String>();
    set.add("click");
    set.add("keydown");
    return set;
}

public void setObject(T object) {
    this.object = object;

}

@Override
protected void onEnterKeyDown(Context context, Element parent, String value,
        NativeEvent event, ValueUpdater<String> valueUpdater) {
    doAction(value, valueUpdater,object);
}

@Override
public void onBrowserEvent(Context context, Element parent,
        String value, NativeEvent event,
        ValueUpdater<String> valueUpdater) {
    super.onBrowserEvent(context, parent, value, event, valueUpdater);

    if ("click".equals(event.getType())) {
        EventTarget eventTarget = (EventTarget) event.getEventTarget();
        if (parent.getFirstChildElement().isOrHasChild(Element.as(eventTarget))) {
            doAction(value, valueUpdater,object);
        }
    }
}

protected abstract void doAction(String value, ValueUpdater<String> valueUpdater,T object);
```

The following class implements HasCell interface.

```
public abstract class ClickableTextCellHasCellImpl<T> implements HasCell<T, String> {

private FieldUpdater<T, String> fieldUpdater;
private T object;
private CustomTextCell<T> cell = new CustomTextCell<T>() {

    @Override
    protected void doAction(String value,
            ValueUpdater<String> valueUpdater, T object) {
        onTextClick(object);
    }

    @Override
    public void render(com.google.gwt.cell.client.Cell.Context context,
            String value, SafeHtmlBuilder sb) {
        sb.appendHtmlConstant("<h4>"+ getValue(object)+"</h4>");            
    }

};

protected abstract void onTextClick(T object);

@Override
public Cell<String> getCell() {
    return cell;
}

@Override
public FieldUpdater<T, String> getFieldUpdater() {
    return fieldUpdater;
}


public void setFieldUpdater(FieldUpdater<T, String> fieldUpdater){
    this.fieldUpdater=fieldUpdater;
}

@Override
public abstract String getValue(T object);

public void setObjectValue(T object){
    this.object = object;
    cell.setObject(object);
}

}
```

You can create a similar class for the Button as well. For the ButtonHasCellImpl just change the render method to:

```
@Override
public void render(com.google.gwt.cell.client.Cell.Context context,
        String value, SafeHtmlBuilder sb) {
        sb.appendHtmlConstant("<button type=\"button\">"+ getValue(object)+"</button>");            
}
```

Finally add them to the composite cell:

```
CompositeCell compositeCell = new CompositeCell(hasCellImplLst);

    Column<MyObject, String> compColum = new Column<MyObject, String>(compositeCell) {

        @Override
        public String getValue(MyObject object) {
            textCell.setObjectValue(object);
            buttonCell.setObjectValue(object);
            return null;
        }
    };
```

To summarize it, you'll have to use a composite cell which in turn uses a list of HasCell implementations.

Comment: can we have simpler solution?